# How to stretch text value in konvaJS to certain width and height?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

In KonvaJS Text Object there is a property ***fontSize*** like `fontSize: 30` but I need to stretch the text according the width and height I give for it.

Here what I wrote:

```js
var textX = new Konva.Text({
            text: 'X',
            align: 'center',
            x: 60,
            y: 60,
            width: 60,
            height: 40
        });
```

What do you suggest to let the code work?

Comment: @lavrton  there should be something straightforward in KonvaJS library?

Comment: The `scaledFontsize` function in my answer is only 6 simple lines long ... that's straightforward. :-)

Comment: @markE creating too much canvases is not friendly with memory.

Comment: There is only 1 canvas and it's only temporarily created. The Garbage Collector will reclaim the memory very quickly.  You can even run `scaledFontSize` with a zero memory footprint. Since the canvas is not used to actually draw on, you can get a reference to your Kinetic/Konva canvas and use it to `measureText`. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text fonts may not incrementally scale to exactly fit a desired width, but you can come close.

- Create an in-memory canvas element,
- Measure your text at a certain `px` testFontsize (almost any reasonable test size will do),
- The needed font size is: `testFontsize*desiredWidth/measuredWidth`,
- Set the needed `px` font size in your Konva.Text.

*Notes: Some fonts do not scale with decimal precision so you might have to `.toFixed(0)` the resulting scaled font size. Some fonts may not incrementally scale at all and you will get the nearest available font size -- which might not fill the desired width well.*

**Example code:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// define the desired text, fontsize and width
var text='Scale Me';
var fontface='verdana';
var desiredWidth=60;

$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:30,max:200}).val(desiredWidth);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){ 
    desiredWidth=parseInt($(this).val());
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    draw(text,fontface,desiredWidth) 
});

draw(text,fontface,desiredWidth);

function draw(text,fontface,desiredWidth){
    // calc the scaled fontsize needed to fill the desired width
    var scaledSize=scaledFontsize(text,fontface,desiredWidth);
    // Demo: draw the text at the scaled fontsize
    ctx.font=scaledSize+'px '+fontface;
    ctx.textAlign='left';
    ctx.textBaseline='middle';
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,desiredWidth,100);
    ctx.fillText(text,0,50);
    ctx.font='14px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(scaledSize+'px '+fontface+' fits '+desiredWidth+'px width',10,125);
}

function scaledFontsize(text,fontface,desiredWidth){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    var testFontsize=18;
    cctx.font=testFontsize+'px '+fontface;
    var textWidth=cctx.measureText(text).width;
    return((testFontsize*desiredWidth/textWidth));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Desired Width:&nbsp<input id=myslider type=range><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=256></canvas>
```